# Pandas get values in one column that are not in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and looking  a way to find missing values in columns 'a' from column 'b'.
How to get the following result?

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[1,2,3],[10,20,30]],
                  'b': [[1,2],[20]]})

df['required'] = [[3],[10,30]]

df

              a       b  required
0     [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2]       [3]
1  [10, 20, 30]    [20]  [10, 30]
```

The column 'c' should have all the elements from column 'a' that are not present in column 'b'.

I am looking for a vectorized way something like 'np.setdiff1d' but I could not find a way to do it. I can do it by using for loop but that would be too inefficient.

## update

- there are no duplicates
- order does not matter

Comment: Does the order of the elements in each list matter? Are there duplicate values in each list?

Comment: There are no duplicates and order does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.setdiff1d`, just inside of `apply`:

```py
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.setdiff1d(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)

df
              a       b         c
0     [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2]       [3]
1  [10, 20, 30]    [20]  [10, 30]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) too but because your data doesn't have duplicates I would set `assume_unique = True` which speeds up computation.

From [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

> assume_unique : bool
>
> ```
> If True, the input arrays are both assumed to be unique, which can speed up the calculation. Default is False.
> ```

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.setdiff1d(x['a'], x['b'], assume_unique=True), axis=1)
```

Alternatively with list comprehension (which should be fast too):

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: [e for e in x['a'] if e not in x['b']], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this answer:

```py
df['c'] = df['a'].apply(set) - df['b'].apply(set)

              a       b  required         c
0     [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2]       [3]       {3}
1  [10, 20, 30]    [20]  [10, 30]  {10, 30}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Make them sets, not lists:
df = df.applymap(set)

# Subtract a from b:
df['required'] = df.a.sub(df.b)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
              a       b  required
0     {1, 2, 3}  {1, 2}       {3}
1  {10, 20, 30}    {20}  {10, 30}
```

---

Another approach using `np.setdiff1d` would be to "vectorize" it. (It's kinda a fake vectorization I believe, but may be nice if you want to do this a lot)

```
setdiff2d = np.vectorize(np.setdiff1d, otypes=[list])
df['required'] = setdiff2d(df['a'], df['b'])

# Output

              a       b  required
0     [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2]       [3]
1  [10, 20, 30]    [20]  [10, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it, by making use of the sets.

```
df['diff']=df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x['a']).difference(set(x['b']))), axis=1)
df
```

```
    a                b      required    diff
0   [1, 2, 3]       [1, 2]  [3]         [3]
1   [10, 20, 30]    [20]    [10, 30]    [10, 30]
```

Comment: I can not upvote, I will need at least 20 reputation to upvote.